Google Cloud Engine wont find google module at start up
I am using Google Cloud Engine VM with Ubuntu 20.04.4 and I am trying to run a start up script that runs a python file. The root user dosent recognise the google module.
Aug 26 16:57:00 instance-20240825-072938 systemd[1]: Starting Google Compute Engine Startup Scripts...
Aug 26 16:57:00 instance-20240825-072938 google_metadata_script_runner[1052]: Starting startup scripts (version 20231004.02-0ubuntu1~20.04.4).
Aug 26 16:57:00 instance-20240825-072938 google_metadata_script_runner[1052]: Found startup-script in metadata.
Aug 26 16:57:01 instance-20240825-072938 google_metadata_script_runner[1052]: startup-script: Traceback (most recent call last):
Aug 26 16:57:01 instance-20240825-072938 google_metadata_script_runner[1052]: startup-script:   File "/home/elias_richard_naess/superprofproj/main_sel2.py", line 4, in <module>
Aug 26 16:57:01 instance-20240825-072938 google_metadata_script_runner[1052]: startup-script:     from google_api_fetch import api_fetch
Aug 26 16:57:01 instance-20240825-072938 google_metadata_script_runner[1052]: startup-script:   File "/home/elias_richard_naess/superprofproj/google_api_fetch.py", line 5, in <module>
Aug 26 16:57:01 instance-20240825-072938 google_metadata_script_runner[1052]: startup-script:     from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
Aug 26 16:57:01 instance-20240825-072938 google_metadata_script_runner[1052]: startup-script: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'
Aug 26 16:57:01 instance-20240825-072938 google_metadata_script_runner[1052]: startup-script exit status 1
Aug 26 16:57:01 instance-20240825-072938 google_metadata_script_runner[1052]: Finished running startup scripts.
Aug 26 16:57:01 instance-20240825-072938 systemd[1]: google-startup-scripts.service: Succeeded.
Aug 26 16:57:01 instance-20240825-072938 systemd[1]: Finished Google Compute Engine Startup Scripts.

I have tried sudo su and pip installing google in every directory that shows when running
python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)".

The start up script is:
#! /bin/bash
/usr/bin/python3 /home/elias_richard_naess/superprofproj/main_sel2.py

The start script finds the python file.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python#install_the_google_client_library

@DanielF Yeah, I imported google, but that wasen't the right modules. Thank you for reminding me which modules to install:)
